# VBA make directed graph undirected

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spread sheet with 2 columns which dictates relationship between 2 vertices (servers). Unfortunately, there are too many columns so there is entry A,B and B,A. I need to get rid of those redundant entries. Can someone provide a function please?

Example:

[image]

Would prefer the output to be separated but it's ok if it modifies the same input columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By answering this question, I hope it gives you a starting point or an idea to understand the basics and come up with your half working solution for the next time.

**Without VBA:**

You can compare strings. In Cell D2 -> `=IF(A2<B2,A2,B2)` gives you the first letter in alphabet among the two letters. Same thing goes to E2 -> `=IF(A2<B2,B2,A2)`. Copy these formulas until the end, then copy/paste them as values, and then remove duplicates from Data ribbon.

**Using VBA:**

You can reorder the letters using comparison again, then concatenate them with a coma in between. Then check them if they exist in your dictionary and add them to dictionary if they do not exist. You can write them to worksheet cells in the process, or you can extract them from your dictionary later on:

```
Sub removeDub()
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim i As Long
Dim s1, s2 As String
'Dim a() As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")
For i = 2 To .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    If Cells(i, 1).Value < Cells(i, 2).Value Then
        s1 = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        s2 = .Cells(i, 2).Value
    Else
        s1 = .Cells(i, 2).Value
        s2 = .Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If

    If Not dict.Exists(s1 & "," & s2) Then
        dict.Add s1 & "," & s2, 1
        .Range("D" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = s1
        .Range("E" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = s2
    End If
Next i

'For Each Key In dict.Keys
'    a = Split(Key, ",")
'    .Range("D" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = a(0)
'    .Range("E" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = a(1)
'Next Key
End With

End Sub
```